# New to Joins concept in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have tow tables in database one is at_reg_user and another is payments. This is my 'at_reg_user' table

[image]

This is my 'payments' table

[image]

What I need is, in admin panel how to show the details of particular user details with id,email,mobile & status with payment table details of particular email with txn_id, payment_gross & payment_status

I have tried with select query with joins but i didn't get it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Including your code may help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.id, p.txn_id, p.payment_gross, payment_status, u.id, u.email, u.mobile, u.status from payments p inner join at_reg_user u on u.email = p.email
```

Breakdown:
We want the primary information to come from payments table.  The user table is just additional information. (**on the flip side, you could get all of the people and then grab all of their payments and total them and such, but...). We are giving an alias to the tables: payment is p, at_reg_user is u.  This is done because "payments" and "at_reg_user" is a pain to type every time.  Be lazy and make it easy on yourself.

Now we have the tables joined by email, we just need to tell the query what to return.  There will be a YUGE problem if email is not a unique identifier on the at_reg_user table.  Much better to have a unique`enter code here id on the payments table that links the people to payments instead of an email!!

Comment: i have made id as primary key and email as unique key in at_reg_user

Answer (score 0):

[image: sql.png]

This is an example of a SQL query that includes JOIN operation.